# Create Xml with Same tag name

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

Table Name : **sample**

Column Name : **id,name**

Every Row Create Separate tag with inside.

Show the Xml value like this

```
<Details>
     <id>1</id>
     <name>na</name>
     <Details>
       <id>2</id>
       <name>aa</name>
     </Details>
   </Details>
```

I tried like this but its not working

```
select 
     id       'Details\id'
     ,name    'Details\name'
from sample
```

How do get that xml output?

Comment: Why node id with value 2 comes inside? it is equal record as 1?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy I need that format. Every row comes inside tag all </Details> comes in end xml. If i have 4 Rows 4 </details> comes end. <details> tag start in every row values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hardcoded but should work:

```
DECLARE @x xml

SELECT @x = (
    SELECT x+''
    FROM (
        SELECT '%details?%id?'+CAST(id as nvarchar(max))+'%/id?%name?'+name+'%/name?' x
        FROM [sample] s
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  '%/details?'
        FROM [sample] s
        ) as t
    FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE((CAST(@x as nvarchar(max))),'%','<'),'?','>') as xml)
```

In `[sample]` table I got:

```
(1,'na'),
(2,'aa'),
(3,'sd')
```

Output:

```
<details>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>na</name>
  <details>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>aa</name>
    <details>
      <id>3</id>
      <name>sd</name>
    </details>
  </details>
</details>
```

**EDIT**

Also it could be done with recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @x xml

;WITH rec AS (
SELECT  CAST((
            SELECT TOP 1    id,
                            [name]
            FROM [sample]
            ORDER BY id DESC
            FOR XML PATH('details')
        ) as xml) as d,
        1 as [Level]
UNION ALL
SELECT  CAST((
            SELECT  id,
                    [name],
                    cast(r.d as xml)
            FROM [sample]
            WHERE s.id = id
            FOR XML PATH('details')
        ) as xml) as d,
        r.[Level]+1
FROM [sample] s
INNER JOIN rec r
    ON s.id = CAST(r.d.query('/details/id/text()') as nvarchar(max))-1
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES d
FROM rec
ORDER BY [Level] desc
```

Same output.

Comment: Strange format, but that's not your fault... greate solution!

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo! I thought first one was a little bit complicated and it could be done with recursive CTE. And yes! It can

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT
        *
    FROM #details
    WHERE id = 2
    FOR xml PATH ('Details'), TYPE)
FROM #details
WHERE id = 1
FOR xml PATH ('Details')
```

For inner loop you can use CTE

Table creation scripts :

```
CREATE TABLE #details (
    id int,
    name varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #details (id, name)
    VALUES (1, 'test'), (2, 'test2')
```

Comment: i give just sample  data. i have more than 2 rows

Comment: As I said for recursive looping you need to use CTE based on your logic. Here I just hard coded on how to do nested xml

Comment: let me try to understand your looping better, if you have for records 1, 2, 3, 4 then your output has to be 1 inside 1 we need to have 2 and inside 2 you need to have 3 and inside 3 you need to have 4 is that correct?

Comment: Is there specific reason why you are generating xml like this? This will be very difficult while using the xml..

Comment: that i need that type of xml